# Android : Proxy settings for MediaPlayer class

Tags: android, proxy, settings, media-player

I'm developing an android application. In this application, I have to play video from HTTP server. I am trying to use MediaPlayer class for playing this HTTP video steam. I am receiving
"Unable play the video" error.

My WI-FI connection requires a proxy for internet access. how to specify these proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
Properties systemSettings=System.getProperties();

systemSettings.put("http.proxyHost", "your.proxy.host.here");
systemSettings.put("http.proxyPort", "8080"); // use actual proxy port
```

However, bear in mind that "Unable play the video" has many potential causes. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the *warnings* or errors that `MediaPlayer` generates, to give you more clues. For example, your video may not be ["safe for streaming"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288883/where-to-place-videos-to-stream-android).

Comment: I tried using 'java.lang.System.setproperty("http.proxyHost", "")' , I got same error... i have also tried using 'android.provider.Settings.System' class to set Http Proxy.. But i got following exception:   **Setting http_proxy has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, value is unchanged....** when i used 'android.provider.Settings.Secure', i got **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS**. I already have the required permission in my manifest file....

Comment: I think it is not possible to set http proxy by non system applications 
[check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385381/android-java-lang-securityexception-on-settings-secure-putstring).

Comment: I am able to play the video, when i used other network which does not require a proxy.  so this error is related to network only.

Comment: I found an application which plays a streaming video...[npr-android-app](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/)... In this application they are using a different approch for playing videos using proxy.. i think it is a workaround... they have implemented a server in their application, which handles the request using URLConnection... and URLConnection has proxy support... they are using this local server address, in MediaPlayer.... like http://localhost/videoid.. is this is only possible way...

Comment: @Ranjith: An ordinary SDK application cannot modify secure settings. The code I list above works for `HttpClient`, and I thought perhaps that `MediaPlayer` might honor it -- apparently, it does not. NPR's local proxy solution obviously works for them, and I do not have any other suggestion to make to you.